# Texture not importing properly

Tags: texturing

When trying to import certain items into blender for Roblox GFX purposes, the texture does not show how it is supposed to. I have tried re exporting the object and importing it to blender, but I get the same result.

The item:

[image: properly textured]

Imported to blender:

[image: improperly textured]

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Here is the blend file
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/7jkAmRaV/

Comment: hello, maybe pack your image and share the file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I added the link to the post

Comment: if you take a look at the picture in the UV Editor, it is exactly what we see in the 3D Viewport as shown by your second screenshot, so I don't know how you could expect to see what we see in picture #1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mesh contains two sets of wings, right on top of each other, with the dark wings "below" the red ones. Here is how you can disentangle them.

First, go into Edit mode and bring up a UV editor. You can see that there are bunch of verts with their UVs in the dark part of the texture. Those are the ones we want to grab.

[image: UV editor]

Turn on "UV Sync Selection". This syncs the selection between the UV editor and 3D view.

[image: Sync selection]

Select the blob in the dark part of the texture...

[image: First selection]

Hold shift to add to the selection, and select the small blob near the top too...

[image: Second selection]

You now have all the verts for the dark wings selected. Move the mouse back to the 3D view, hit g to drag the selected verts, and move them away. You should now see both pairs of wings.

[image: Final]